# How can I execute a method in opener window from a modal window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, window.opener

I'm using a jQuery plugin for notifications: http://needim.github.com/noty/

This is the way I call the method that displays the notification:

```
noty({force: true, timeout: false, text: 'Hello noty', type: 'information'});
```

The code works fine, but now, being in a modal window, I need to execute that call in the opener window as soon as I close the modal window... I think I should use window.opener but don't know how to do it for this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could define a JS function in your opener window:

```
function invokeSuccessNotification(msg){
        noty({force: true, timeout: false, text: 'Hello noty', type: 'information'});

    }
```

then, in your modal window, call that method like this:

```
window.opener.invokeSuccessNotification();
```